# How to set independent path in QgsOverlayAnalyzer >> intersection statement using Python?

Tags: qgis, python, intersection, analysis

How to set independent path in QgsOverlayAnalyzer >> intersection statement using Python?

```
QgsOverlayAnalyzer.intersection(QgsVectorLayer, QgsVectorLayer, QString, bool onlySelectedFeatures=False, QProgressDialog p=None)
```

In Qstring statement one has to define the output path and output shapefile name of the intersection. But if I use intersection inside a plugin, is there a way to set this path independent of the user? What I mean is that the path should be something like C:\users..*username*..etc but how can this be independent if the username? Should my plugin somehow read a path in the users computer and use this as the ouptut path? Is this possible?

My plugin uses as inputs vector layers ones that are visible in the table of contents using self.iface.legendInterface().

And another question, after the ouptut file is produced how should I open it the current map (make it visible in the table of contents)?

Comment: Perhaps the code used in this [post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53588/how-to-use-memory-layers-in-qgis-plugin-to-store-results-of-geoprocessing-tools) may answer both your questions.

Answer (score 1):

So after Joseph 's very very heplful comment and the link suggested the following is working in my plugin:

```
 ##
 from qgis.analysis import * 
 from PyQt4.QtGui import QFileDialog
 ##

    ##path definition: code copied & pasted from _init_(self, iface) method
    ##from the plugin' s main module & CLASSNAME: the plugin' s classname
    locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]
    locale_path = os.path.join(
    self.plugin_dir,
    'i18n',
    'CLASSNAME_{}.qm'.format(locale))
        if os.path.exists(locale_path):
            self.translator = QTranslator()
            self.translator.load(locale_path)

                if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
                    QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)
    ##
    overlayAnalyzer = QgsOverlayAnalyzer()

    intersection_result= "result_name" 
    intersection_result_path = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self.dlg,"Save result as", locale_path, "shapefiles (*.shp)")
    overlayAnalyzer.intersection(layer1, slayer2, intersection_result_path, 0) 
    self.iface.addVectorLayer(intersection_result_path, intersection_result, 'ogr')
```

Still a question how to implement this without prompting a dialog to the user during plugin' s running time.. (but still not have put coding effort on this on my own.. a task for the next days..)

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!!! Still prompting a dialog during plugin run time, but independent of user and OS

```
 ##
 from qgis.analysis import * 
 from PyQt4.QtGui import QFileDialog
 from os.path import expanduser
 ##

    ##path definition independent from user and os
    user_path = os.path.expanduser("~")

    overlayAnalyzer = QgsOverlayAnalyzer()
    intersection_result= "result_name" 
    intersection_result_path = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self.dlg,"Save result as", user_path, "shapefiles (*.shp)")

    overlayAnalyzer.intersection(layer1, slayer2, intersection_result_path, 0) 
    self.iface.addVectorLayer(intersection_result_path, intersection_result, 'ogr')
```